# Why does Django's union mess up the column order?

Tags: python, django

If I have 2 models:

```py
class Hero(models.Model):
    hero_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hero_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    hero_identity = models.TextField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hero_name

class Villain(models.Model):
    villain_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    villain_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    villain_identity = models.TextField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.villain_name
```

and I create some test instances:

```py
Hero(hero_name="Superman", hero_age=30, hero_identity="Clark Kent").save()
Hero(hero_name="Iron Man", hero_age=35, hero_identity="Tony Stark").save()
Hero(hero_name="Spider-Man", hero_age=18, hero_identity="Peter Parker").save()

Villain(villain_name="Green Goblin", villain_age=45, villain_identity="Norman Osborn").save()
Villain(villain_name="Red Skull", villain_age=38, villain_identity="Johann Schmidt").save()
Villain(villain_name="Vulture", villain_age=47, villain_identity="Adrian Toomes").save()
```

Listing them individually works fine, but listing them using a union breaks the order somehow:

```py
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> from myapp.models import Hero, Villain

>>> for hero in Hero.objects.all().annotate(name=F("hero_name"), age=F("hero_age"), identity=F("hero_identity")).values("name", "age", "identity"):
...     print(hero)

{'name': 'Superman', 'age': 30, 'identity': 'Clark Kent'}
{'name': 'Iron Man', 'age': 35, 'identity': 'Tony Stark'}
{'name': 'Spider-Man', 'age': 18, 'identity': 'Peter Parker'}

>>> for villain in Villain.objects.all().annotate(name=F("villain_name"), age=F("villain_age"), identity=F("villain_identity")).values("name", "age", "identity"):
...     print(villain)

{'name': 'Green Goblin', 'age': 45, 'identity': 'Norman Osborn'}
{'name': 'Red Skull', 'age': 38, 'identity': 'Johann Schmidt'}
{'name': 'Vulture', 'age': 47, 'identity': 'Adrian Toomes'}

>>> all = Hero.objects.all().annotate(name=F("hero_name"), age=F("hero_age"), identity=F("hero_identity")).union(Villain.objects.all().annotate(name=F("villain_name"), age=F("villain_age"), identity=F("villain_identity")))
>>> for person in all.values("name", "age", "identity"):
...     print(person)

{'name': 1, 'age': 'Green Goblin', 'identity': 45}
{'name': 1, 'age': 'Superman', 'identity': 30}
{'name': 2, 'age': 'Iron Man', 'identity': 35}
{'name': 2, 'age': 'Red Skull', 'identity': 38}
{'name': 3, 'age': 'Spider-Man', 'identity': 18}
{'name': 3, 'age': 'Vulture', 'identity': 47}
```

The values in the `name` column appear to be the values of the `id` column for each row, the name values are in the `age` column, the `age` values in the `identity` column, and the `identity` values don't appear at all.

Note: To list them individually, I obviously don't need that `annotate` - I can just use the original column names - but with the annotate, I'm keeping the data as close to the pre-union operation as possible.

Note: This is using Django version 3.2.7

Comment: Why not to annotate id column as well, so you will have 4 annotated column instead of one and give it one try?

Comment: @HusamAlhwadi annotate just adds columns. It doesn't remove the columns that were going to be returned in the first place. That means the `id` column is already present in the output, and unless you add another `id` column with a new name, Django won't let you add a duplicate `id` column. I'm not sure how adding a new `id` column with a new name will help, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @DušanMaďar I read through those answers, but honestly couldn't follow it on the first pass. I'll be looking at it again later today.

Comment: you already have annotated 3 columns except id column however your issue is in the values of these columns , so I suggest you to annotate id column so you will have 4 columns instead of 3, hopes this will eliminate the mismatching in column values, bearing in mind that only value of id column is available under name column,  really I didn't face such case before but I just suggest ...

Comment: @HusamAlhwadi annotate doesn't do what you think it does. You can't annotate the `id` column because it's already there. It's not there because I listed it explicitly - I didn't. It's there implicitly. If you try to annotate it, you get a `ValueError: The annotation 'id' conflicts with a field on the model.` exception. I appreciate you trying to help, but what you suggest can't be done.

Comment: My actual models and queries are quite large and complex, and I'm having a hard time boiling them down to a simple example. Doing some reading and experimenting, I can solve this sample by using `values` instead of `annotate`, but it doesn't help with my real problem. I'll try to re-ask the question with a slightly different example.